# Calling a servlet from maven

Tags: maven, servlets, build

I want to upload automatically a zip file with Maven build. The uploading of file is done in a servlet. Is there a way to call the servlet from a Maven file?

Comment: If you can invoke curl or wget to do what you want, you can make Maven execute that command line.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more in detail what you problem is?